# How can I add objects to a list of variable size from user input?

Tags: c#, oop

I am a newbie on C# and I am trying to make a program to handle orders from customers. I created my object and added a method to read the user input but I am still struggling with creating a list where user can add products by putting in their properties ( name, code and price).

Here is what I got so far :

```cs
public class Produit
{
    public string? NomProduits { get;  set; }
    public  string? CodeProduits { get;  set; }
    public  string? PrixProduits { get;  set; }
}

public class AttributsProduits
{
   
    public static void AjouterProduits ()
    {
        Produit ReadProduits()
        {
            return new Produit()
            {
                NomProduits = Console.ReadLine(),
                CodeProduits = Console.ReadLine(),
                PrixProduits = Console.ReadLine(),
            };
        }
    }
}
```

I created the object and its attributes, and added a method to read said attributes from the user. This is what I did for the list but Im getting an error CS1729 :

```cs
List<Produit> produits = new List<Produit>();

produits.Add(new Produit(NomProduits));
produits.Add(new Produit(CodeProduits));
produits.Add(new Produit(PrixProduits));
```

Can anyone help me with this please?

Adding objects to an existing list

Comment: Assume we don't memorize all possible error codes for all possible programming languages.  Please indicate the error message and which operation produces the error message.

Comment: Just write `produits.Add(ReadProduits());` instead or `produits.Add(new Produit{ (NomProduits="n", CodeProduits="c", PrixProduits="p" });`

Comment: But somehow you have nested the read method in another one, strange!

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use a constructor which accepts a single value as a parameter:

```
new Produit(NomProduits)
```

But your class has no defined constructors (and therefor has only the default parameterless constructor):

```
public class Produit
{
    public string? NomProduits { get; set; }
    public string? CodeProduits { get; set; }
    public string? PrixProduits { get; set; }
}
```

You can use the parameterless constructor:

```
new Produit()
```

Or perhaps specify the value in an object initializer:

```
new Produit { NomProduits = NomProduits }
```

Or define a constructor:

```
public class Produit
{
    public string? NomProduits { get; set; }
    public string? CodeProduits { get; set; }
    public string? PrixProduits { get; set; }

    public Produit(string nomProduits)
    {
        NomProduits = nomProduits;
    }
}
```

Note that in the case of the constructor this explicitly defines which of the three properties are initialized by the constructor parameter.  So your next two objects may not quite make sense.  You could define constructors that take multiple parameters, use object initializers in each case, etc.

What logic you build is up to you.  The point is that in order to use a specific constructor you need to first define that constructor.